# How to run JUnit 5 test in Spring Test Suite?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

STS: 3.9.7.RELEASE

SpringBoot Project: 2.1.1.RELEASE

Effective POM shows `<junit.version>4.12</junit.version>`. I was hoping to work with JUnit 5 and I'm also a bit surprised that SpringBoot adds JUnit 4 dependency. Should I add JUnit 5 dependency manually to POM or is it better not to mess with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have to add JUnit5 manually as `spring-boot-starter-test` by default include JUnit4 only.

First , exclude JUnit4 from `spring-boot-starter-test` :

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude JUnit 4 -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Then include JUnit5 dependencies:

```xml
    <!-- Actual Junit5 implementation. Will transitively include junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For junit5 parameterised test support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Only required to run junit5 test from IDE -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

---

Update On 14-Feb-2020 : Since Spring Boot 2.2 , [JUnit5 is included by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#junit-5).

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider also excluding: groupId: `org.junit.vintage`, artifactId: `junit-vintage-engine`, which is also present in later versions of `spring-boot-starter-test`, and which also contains JUnit4 classes.